# How do I access JSON data returned from an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a JavaScript function that receives data from an AJAX call to the server.

```
function dataReceiver() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        // Everything is good, the response was received.
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            //console.log( JSON.parse(this.responseText) );
            let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log("1) " + data["key1"]);
            console.log("2) " + data['key1']);
            console.log("3) " + data.key1);

        } else {
            // There was a problem with the request.
            alert("Error: HTTP request status " + httpRequest.status);
        }
    } else {
        // Not ready yet.
        console.log("Request status: " + httpRequest.status);
    }
}
```

The data is sent in JSON format, and it is being received correctly.  The commented `console.log()` line returns

```
{"key1": "stringValue1", "key2": "stringValue2", "key3": intValue}
```

with keys and values exactly as expected.

However, I cannot access this data.  The three uncommened `console.log()` lines show the ways I've tried to get access to this data, and the console shows

1. undefined
2. undefined
3. undefined

How do I access JSON data returned by an AJAX request?

There are several other questions on this site with similar problems, but all that I can find involve things that don't apply to this situation, like React, jQuery, or PHP.  This is plain JavaScript.

**Edit:**  If I don't try parsing the JSON, the raw response comes back as

```
console.log( this.responseText );
-> "{\"key1\": \"stringValue1\", \"key2\": \"stringValue2\", \"key3\": intValue}"
```

which is just the expected JSON object with escape backslashes for the double-quotes.

Comment: You should try first `console.log(data)` so you can be sure what data you actually got

Comment: You sure that object isn't inside an array? What does `console.log(this.reponseText)` show?

Comment: For example, in ASP.NET all AJAX (At least in webform) is automatically enclosed by `{d: result}`, so in dhat case you use `console.log("1) " + data.d.key1])`. Also, remember that it is case sensitive (may be it is "Key"?)

Comment: @charlietfl  It's not inside an array.  The raw response is the same as the JSON object, just with escape backslashes for the quotes.  I've edited the full expression into my question.

Comment: Try to check data type with typeof, maybe the object is already a JSON and you are trying to parse again. Nowadays you don't need to use parse, is in deprecation. All you need to do is make sure response Content-Type is application/json and it will come to you as a object already! Parse is to parse a STRING representation of a JSON.

Comment: @Marco `typeof` the raw data `this.responseText` and the parsed `JSON.parse(this.responseText)` are both `string`.  Trying to access keys of the raw data directly gives the same result: three 'undefined' values.  The data is being sent by Django's `JsonResponse()` function, which automatically sets its Content-Type to `application/json`.

Comment: If type is string after parse() then perhaps you have nested json but that is not what has been shown here

Comment: Sorry i'v read it again and I agree with @charlietfl, maybe you have something, have you tried to validate is first? take the responseText string and try to validate at https://jsonlint.com.

Answer (score 0):

The function `dataReceiver()` shown in the question is the correct way to access JSON data returned from an AJAX request.

In this case, the error results from the *sending* function double-encoding the returned data as JSON.  The first encoding converts the data into a string for transmission, which is how it's supposed to work.  The second encoding then adds escape characters to that string, which breaks the encoding.

**The raw JSON logged by** `console.log( this.responseText );` **should not contain escape slashes**.  This is the clearest indicator of the error that the data has been JSON-encoded twice.

In principle, this error might occur using any method of sending data from the server.  In this particular case, the data was sent from a Django view using

```
return JsonResponse(json.dumps(response), safe=False)
```

where I intended Python's `json.dumps()` function to perform the JSON-encoding; however, Django's built-in `JsonResonse()` *also* performs JSON-encoding, which is sort of obvious when you think about it, but I managed not to think about it; hence the double JSON-encoding.  Simplifying this to

```
return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

allowed the data to transmit and be interpreted correctly by the receiving JavaScript function.